# Select sum of zero if no records in second table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I did some research and learned about the `COALESCE(sum(num), 0)` function. The issue is the example I found only related to using one table.

I am calculating a sum from a second table, and if there are no records for an item in the second table, I still want it to show up in  my query and have a sum of zero.

```
SELECT note.user, note.product, note.noteID, note.note, COALESCE(sum(noteTable.Score), 0) as points 
FROM note, noteTable
WHERE note.user <> 3 AND note.noteID = noteTable.noteID
```

I am only recieving results if there is an entry in the second table noteTable. If there are scores added for a note, I still want them to show up in the result with a points value of zero.

Table Examples:

**Note**

```
user | product | noteID |note
3        1         1       Great
3        2         2       Awesome
4        1         3       Sweet
```

**NoteTable**

```
noteID | score
1          5
```

The query should show me this:

```
user | noteID | sum(points)
3        1          5
3        2          0
4        3          0
```

But I am only getting this:

```
user | noteID | sum(points)
3        1          5
```

Comment: When putting up MySQL, including the table format and some dummy data helps _a lot_ for users trying to answer your question. Otherwise people just have to assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aae812/2

```
SELECT 
  note.user, 
  note.product, 
  note.noteID, note.note, 
  COALESCE(sum(noteTable.Score),0) as points 
FROM note
LEFT JOIN noteTable
ON note.noteID = noteTable.noteID
WHERE note.user <> 3
```

and I guess you should add:

```
GROUP BY note.noteid
```

if you expect to get `SUM` for every `user`. So you want to get more then 1 record back.

Comment: I am trying to get a sum for every note. But the above, does not return any results fro notes with no entries in the second table.

Comment: Since I have no idea what do you mean by `every note` probably you have `note.id` (you should `GROUP BY note.id`). But even better if you can provide an sqlfiddle with some data sample.

Comment: tried to make tables, but the formatting did not show up at all. Not even new lines....

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax and table aliases.  The answer to your question is `SUM()` along with `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT n.user, n.product, n.noteID, n.note,
       COALESCE(sum(nt.Score), 0) as points 
FROM note n LEFT JOIN
     noteTable nt
     ON n.noteID = nt.noteID
WHERE n.user <> 3
GROUP BY n.user, n.product, n.noteID, n.note;
```

You also need a `GROUP BY`.